# How to augment an UMD module definition in TypeScript 2

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

I'm currently writing TypeScript definition files for two libraries that should be consumed through the new `@types` approach. Both follow the UMD pattern. You can either consume them as a module or by referencing them in a `<script>` tag.

The first one was straight forward to write since the two ways of consumption would look like this:

```
import { AccessManager } from 'twilio-common';
const manager = new AccessManager('XXXXXXXX');
```

or

```
const manager = new Twilio.AccessManager('XXXXXXXX');
```

I solved this by using the new `export as namespace` feature of TypeScript 2:

```
import { Promise } from 'es6-promise';

export as namespace Twilio;

export class AccessManager {
  constructor(initialToken: string);
  identity: string | null;
  // omitted
}
```

Now for the second module this becomes a bit more tricky and why I'm writing here.

Consumption via module:

```
import { AccessManager } from 'twilio-common';
import { Client } from 'twilio-ip-messaging';

const manager = new AccessManager('XXXXXXXX');
const client = new Client(manager);
```

Consumption via `<script>` tag:

```
const manager = new Twilio.AccessManager('XXXXXXXX');
const client = new Twilio.IPMessaging.Client('XXXXXXXX');
```

So as you can see the things that are exported in the second defintion files should be exported using a line like:

```
export as namespace Twilio.IPMessaging;
```

However that doesn't work. Since I can't find out what's the proper solution here, I'm turning to StackOverflow for advice.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Dominik

Answer (score 2):

You could also declare a twilio namespace with a sub namespace of IPMessaging and export "Twilio" as the global namespace.

It will make Twilio show up as an importable target for modules though